# bash: File not found

Tags: files, find

It's all on the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: Make sure that the 'emulator' file has executor permissions. use `chmod +x emulator` in that directory.

Comment: souenzzo@VPCEG13EB:~/android-sdk-linux/tools$ chmod +x emulator
souenzzo@VPCEG13EB:~/android-sdk-linux/tools$ ./emulator
bash: ./emulator: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado....
nothing has changed

Comment: That's odd. What's the output of `ls -l | grep emulator`?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run 32 bit application on hybrid 64/32 bit system without basic 32 bit libraries. Check output of

```
uname -a
file emulator
```

You need to install 32 bit version of libc (i386) and some other other libraries that you will need. Check output of

```
ldd emulator
```

and install other 32 bit libraries.